# Jupyterlab: How to remove/hide default "Python 3" Kernel?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am running a custom-configured Jupyterlab installation for our company. It is wired to Livy and Spark to provide PySpark and Spark kernels, which works fine.

However, there is still the default `Python 3` Kernel I want to remove:
[image: Kernels]

When dropping to a console into the pod and doing a `jupyter kernelspec list`, I get, as expected:

```
Available kernels:
  pysparkkernel    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pysparkkernel
  python3          /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  sparkkernel      /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/sparkkernel
```

When I `jupyter kernelspec remove python3`, and reload Jupyterlab, the Python 3 Kernel is still there, and it reappears in the list:

```
Available kernels:
  python3          /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/resources
  pysparkkernel    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pysparkkernel
  sparkkernel      /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/sparkkernel
```

Even when I delete this `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ipykernel/resources` dir the kernel doesn't disappear.

Is it even possible to disable this default kernel or do I have to live with it?

## Workaround

I got what I wanted by copying everything from the `pysparkkernel` into the `python3` dir and removing the `pysparkkernel`, effectively making Jupyterlab think that the PySpark kernel is the default one.

While this works, I am still interested if this is the only way.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to removing the kernel spec you need to turn off `ensure_native_kernel` option which makes sure that the default kernel is always included by adding:

```
c.KernelSpecManager.ensure_native_kernel = False
```

to your configuration file. You can set this via command line too:

```
jupyter lab --KernelSpecManager.ensure_native_kernel=False
```

as explained in https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3674

Note: if you are using JupyterLab 3.x with `jupyter_server`, the configuration is now stored in `jupyter_server_config.py` rather than `jupyter_notebook_config.py` as explained in the [migration guide](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators/migrate-from-nbserver.html).

Comment: I am generating the config on the fly when first starting Jupyterlab to be able to configure things with environment variables put into the Kubernetes deployment file. I will try this option.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I added the line to my config but after removing the default kernel it is still there. I am using Jupyterlab with Jupyterhub though.

Comment: Are you sure that you are editing the correct configuration file? JupyterHub has not switched to jupyter_server yet (although it may change with JupyterLab 3.0.6)