# Modifying default kernel name in a Vertex AI User Managed Notebook instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-lab, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

**TL;DR**

How do you change the kernel display name of the default base conda environment in a Vertex AI User Managed Notebook instance using a Dockerfile or post-startup script?

**Details**

In a Vertex AI User Managed Notebook instance, the Launcher shows the default "base" conda environment kernel as "Python 3 (ipykernel)". I would like to change this display name. There are various threads on how to change or disable/hide this kernel within Jupyter Notebooks ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709500/change-default-kernel-in-jupyter-notebook), [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3338#issuecomment-668168649), [here](https://groups.google.com/g/jupyter/c/dV-lRoyhQ2A), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65954044/jupyterlab-how-to-remove-hide-default-python-3-kernel)). However, I am not having much luck in the context of Vertex AI User Managed Notebooks.

Could someone please describe how to do this, preferably from within a Dockerfile (which I use to create an image from which the Notebook instance is built), or if that isn't possible, from a post-startup script applied during Notebook instance creation? In the end, I would like to be able to open a brand new Notebook instance and see that the base environment's exposed kernel has a name of my choosing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following lines to the Docker file used to create an image from which a Vertex AI User Managed Notebook is generated, properly alters the *display* name of the default kernel tied to the base conda environment. The environment's actual name remains the same, as you can't change the name of the base environment [per documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/rename.html#:%7E:text=Renames%20an%20existing%20environment.,active%20environment%20cannot%20be%20renamed.). The second line may or may not be necessary depending on your set-up.

```
RUN sed -i 's/Python 3 (ipykernel)/someNewEnvName/' /opt/conda/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
RUN rm /root/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/base/kernel.json
```